# Conditional redirects to child routes

Tags: angular, router

I have a scenario where I have lazy loaded child routes to be displayed conditionally:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    canActivate: [ParentGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child1', loadChildren:'./child1/child1.module#Child1Module'
      },
     {
        path: 'child2', loadChildren:'./child2/child2.module#Child2Module'
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

I navigate to `ParentComponent` from some page like:

```
this.router.navigate('app/parent');
```

Now the issue is that I've to show **child1** and **child2** components based on some condition.

For this I added a Guard,

```
      canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    if (this.isAdmin) {
      this.router.navigate(['app/parent/child1']);
      return false;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['app/parent/child2']);
return false;
    }
    return true;
      }
```

However, this causes this guard to be called repeatedly and my app hangs. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you try `this.router.navigate(['/child1']);` ?

Comment: It gives me the error Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'child1'

Answer (score 0):

If someone heed this, here is the solutuion

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        children:[]
        canActivate: [ParentGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'child1', loadChildren:'./child1/child1.module#Child1Module'
      },
      {
        path: 'child2', loadChildren:'./child2/child2.module#Child2Module'
      },
    ]
  }
];
```